# SQL Server Array or dynamic field headings or pivot

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, dynamic, pivot

I am using SQL Server 2012 and not sure on the best way to approach a problem.  This is my data:

```
Item   Size   SortOrder    Qty
ABC    XS      1            0
ABC    S       2            8
ABC    M       3            4
ABC    L       4            3
ZXY    1       1            10
DEF    6       1            5
DEF    8       2            4
DEF    10      3            7
DEF    12      4            6
QWE    1       1            5
```

However, I need to present it in grid format and the size needs to dynamically change as the heading:

```
ABC   XS   S   M   L
Qty   0    8   4   3
ZXY   1
Qty   10
DEF   6    8   10   12
Qty   5    4   7     6
QWE   1
Qty   5
```

Also I need to assign the qty to appropriate size and the size must always display left to right in order of the sort order.

What will be the best method?  Create array or can I achieve the above in a pivot?

Thanks.

I've tried to pivot using the below but keep receiving the error 'Invalid column name 'Item':

```
DECLARE @SizeColums VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @SizeColums = COALESCE(@SizeColums + ',','') + QUOTENAME([Size])
FROM    vw_SizeSeq 
GROUP BY [Size]

DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    SELECT  Item,
            [Types],' +
            @SizeColums + '
    FROM    (SELECT * FROM vw_SizeSeq 
    ) t
    UNPIVOT ( 
         [Type]
        FOR [Types] IN ([Item])) up
    PIVOT (
        MAX([Type])
        FOR [Size] IN (' + @SizeColums + ')
    ) p
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: In SQL we can produce results only in table format, but your expected result looks something different. Try application layer for this

Comment: they must be a way to pivot and unpivot

Comment: May be am not understanding your expected result format. Can you make it some more clear

Comment: think of it as a grid \ pivot \ cross tab where the sizes will need to be dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not pretty, but I think perhaps this may work

```
Declare @XML xml = (Select Item,Size,SortOrder,Qty=isnull(Qty,0) from YourTable for XML RAW),@SQL varchar(max) = ''

-- Create SQL for columns
Select @SQL = @SQL+',Col'+cast(SortOrder as varchar(25))+' = max(case when ColNr='+cast(SortOrder as varchar(25))+' then Value else '''' end)'+char(13)
 From  (Select Distinct SortOrder From YourTable) A Order by SortOrder

-- Normalize Data
Select Itm      = r.value('@Item','varchar(25)')
      ,ColNr     = r.value('@SortOrder','int')
      ,Attribute = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
      ,Value     = attr.value('.','varchar(max)')
 Into  #Temp
 From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)
 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
 Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('Item','SortOrder')

-- Create Final SQL and Execute
Set @SQL = 'Select Item=case when Attribute=''Qty'' then '''' else Itm end'+@SQL+' From #Temp Group By Itm,Attribute Order By Itm,Attribute Desc'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Returns

```
Item    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
ABC     XS      S       M       L
        0       8       4       3
DEF     6       8       10      12
        5       4       7       6
QWE     1           
        5           
ZXY     1           
        10
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I don't get the same result though - I get the item down the left with is correct but then all the possible sort order numbers along the top as column headings - I need these to be the item sizes.

Comment: No.  Each item can have a different size range.  In the original data at the top, Item ABC has sizes XS \ S \ M \ L, DEF has sizes 6 \ 8 \ 10 \ 12 ZXY is only in size 1 and QWE is only in size 1.  These need to be the dynamic column headings

Comment: 4 rows yes, plus the qty under the size.  I only want to show the size if the size exists for the item though like the results in the 2nd part of my original post

Comment: @Michael Clearly I'm not understanding your requirements.  As far as I can see my results mirror what you posted with the exception of blank lines and the repeating Item..  If you want different column names (and counts) for each item, that would be multiple datasets

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.

Comment: I have slightly changed the how I need the data in the original post if that helps.

Comment: better but not quite there - can I send you a screenshot?  I've mocked up how it needs to look.

Comment: Thanks - let me take a look.  Yes it will need to handle nulls I'm afraid.  Many thanks for your help - I appreciate it.

Comment: The sizes do not come through as column headings, only the sort order - I have emailed a screenshot.

Comment: Qty2 is required yes, and yes, it is based on a SQL view not a table.

Comment: Will I be able to show both qty's under 1 size?

Comment: I'll have to leave for the day I'm afraid.....

Comment: John - the answer you provided works!!! Many thanks.  If the size is non-numeric though I get an error about converting to .int - should I just make it varchar?